# Can a user answer a question more than once?

Tags: discussion, answers, multiple-answers

Yesterday while reviewing I came across a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25981526/2246380) which had two answers posted by the same user (the same user asked the question) and it felt strange that Stack Overflow allows the a user to answer a question more than once. Shouldn't a user edit his/her existing answer to the question to add more content/details instead of adding a new answer? Why is Stack Overflow allowing the same user to post more than one answer on a question?

I understand there can be cases where they can be more than one completely different answers. Most of such questions can be closed as too broad in my perspective. But allowing the same user to post more than one answer seems like allowing rep farming where a user might break a detailed answer into parts and gather reputation.

Answer (score 4):

Note that when you try to **Add Another Answer**, an alert pops up reading:

> Are you sure you want to add another answer?
>
> You could use the edit link to refine and improve your existing answer, instead.

So although it *is* acceptable to add another answer under certain circumstances (as the linked question puts it, *"when each of the answers, on its own, could be a valid and complete answer to the question"*), it is made clear that doing so is something you should consider carefully.

If a user splits their answer into multiple parts just to try and gain rep, I would expect them to get down-votes and "not an answer" flags for their trouble.

Comment: @Deduplicator much obliged